# difference of javascript input in computer and phone

Tags: javascript

I have created a sudoku game in js. Program  allow only 1-9 numbers. When I run it on my android phone the program will accept all letters and digits.

That is the code didn't work in Android. what can I do for solve it.

Thanks in advance!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input").keydown(function (e) {
        if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 49 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 97 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: U mean whenever you click on text it should show only number pad right???

Comment: Is your input `type = 'number'`?

Comment: use pattern <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" />

Comment: yes. but i dont want  '0'  digit

Comment: @josutty <input type="number" pattern="[1-9]*" />   then use this.No need to write your javascript and all.

Comment: it shows an arrow on my text box. i dont want it

Comment: @josutty what arrow?

Comment: an up and down arrow shown as in combo box for incrementing and decrementing the numbers. i dont want it. i created a sudoku game

Comment: @josutty <input type="tel" pattern="[1-9]*" placeholder='click here to type'/>  .Try this. go to link for demo https://jsfiddle.net/xfw2masx/2/

Comment: @josutty open above url in mobile. and see . It opens number pad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just allow all input, then refine it after it's entered the field:

```
$('input').on('input', function (e) {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^1-9]/g, ''); //remove anything not 1-9
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all - change `<input type="text">` to `<input type="number">` for touch device to show numbers keyboard.

Then filter your input with RegEx:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input").keyup(function () {
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^1-9]/g, ''));
    });
})
```